# Jenkins build via SSH, artifacts on host but not in workspace?

Tags: jenkins

I've started with a new company and a very convoluted build methodology.  The best way I've found to build projects is to command Jenkins to SSH into the build server and execute a string of commands there.

Building by executing shell commands using SSH works well, but the build artifacts don't show up in the Jenkins workspace.  Therefore, I can't seem to archive the artifacts directly to Jenkins.

Is there a way to correct this or work around it?  Can Jenkins be set up to archive files from outside the workspace?

Comment: If your goal is to execute build steps on specific nodes, then you should probably add them as nodes within Jenkins. Then you can specify that specific node within your Jenkins job. If you need to move artifacts from a build node back to the master, look into stash / unstash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've added your build node as a node (slave), here's a stash / unstash example

Stash on the build node

```
stage ('Stash file on node 1') {
    node ('some_build_node') {
        dir ('/tmp') {
            stash name: 'TestTransfer', includes: 'foo.jar'
        }
    }
}
```

Unstash on the master

```
stage ('Unstash file on node 2') {
    node ('master') {
        // If you don't use a 'dir' block, it'll unstash in the workspace
        // which is handy if you then want to archive the artifacts
        dir ('/tmp') {
            unstash 'TestTransfer'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use a slave node (as far as I can tell) because I need to maintain part of the build environment between builds.  I can't start from a completely clean workspace every time.

Comment: OK but I still see stash / unstash as a solution to this problem. You can unstash files on the master outside of the workspace. If you come up with a way to track, let's call them "build groups - A group of builds that are logically connected", you could create a directory outside of the workspace with an ID, use that during the builds, and then move all of the artifacts to the workspace at the end of the builds. Anyway, just an idea.